# How can I create a matrix with a specific math equation?

Tags: r, math, matrix, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have huge data set. The data consists of 371 genotypes (start with gwas) with 105000 markers. I need to have a matrix among genotypes in R with a specific math equation using the 105000 markers. The data format as follow

```
markers  gwas_100   gwas_101    gwas_102    gwas_103
S1_147748   NA  NA  NA  NA
S1_239131   0.67385 0.67385 0.67385 0.67385
S1_644966   0.61051 0.61051 0.61051 0.61051
S1_1625764  NA  0.71429 NA  0.71429
S1_1761929  0.69137 0.69137 0.69137 0.69137
S1_1778021  0.72372 0.72372 0.72372 0.72372
S1_1778059  0.72507 0.72507 0.72507 0.72507
S1_1778136  0.68733 0.68733 0.68733 0.68733
S1_1778289  0.69946 0.69946 0.69946 0.69946
S1_1780669  0.73046 0.73046 0.73046 0.73046
S1_1786636  0.71563 0.71563 0.71563 0.71563
S1_1786639  0.71833 0.71833 0.71833 0.71833
S1_1786640  0.71294 0.71294 0.71294 0.71294
S1_1786678  0.71429 0.71429 0.71429 0.71429
S1_1963487  0.72776 0.72776 0.72776 0.72776
S1_2036329  0.74259 0.74259 0.74259 0.74259
S1_2036386  0.74394 0.74394 0.74394 0.74394
S1_2037735  0.7628  0.7628  0.7628  0.7628
S1_2037760  0.7628  0.7628  0.7628  0.7628
S1_2037773  0.7628  0.7628  0.7628  0.7628
S1_2042132  0.58491 NA  NA  NA
```

math equation

```
(gwas_100 & gwas_101) = Sum (gwas100) - sum (gwas_101), where
sum gwas_100 = 0.67385 + 0.61051 + 0.69137.....+0.58491)
sum gwas_101 = 0.67385 + 0.61051+ ....... 0.7228), therefore
(gwas_100 & gwas_101) = 13.4905 - 13.61994 = -0.12938
```

then I need to get matrix between each two and with all possible combination of the 371 genotypes
like as an example

```
      gwas_100 gwas101 gwas_102 gwas_103
gwas_100          -0.12   0.14      0.05
gwas_101                   0.06     0.1 
gwwas_102                           0.07
gwas_103
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can first use `colSums` to sum up the columns ignoring `NA`s, then substract them by pair using `outer`:

```
sums <- colSums(data[-1], na.rm=TRUE)
outer(sums,sums,`-`)
         gwas_100 gwas_101 gwas_102 gwas_103
gwas_100  0.00000 -0.12938  0.58491 -0.12938
gwas_101  0.12938  0.00000  0.71429  0.00000
gwas_102 -0.58491 -0.71429  0.00000 -0.71429
gwas_103  0.12938  0.00000  0.71429  0.00000
```

Comment: Thanks so you answer. I would like also use a complex equation. e.g

Comment: Thanks so you answer. I would like also use a complex equation. e.g   gwas_ 100& gwas_101 = Sum (p1 - p2)^2/105854. where P1 and p2 are the numbers in gwas_100 and gwas_101 for one marker. In other words, I need to subtract the values in column one from column 2 then sum up the difference then ^2 it. Thanks in advance. Your time and efforts are highly appreciated

Comment: @AhmedSallam This is a very different question, so you have to put the whole calculation into the outer, which will have a lower performance. You can try : `outer(names(data[,-1]),names(data[,-1]),function(x,y){colSums((data[,x]-data[,y])**2, na.rm=TRUE)})`